# Proving with Direct method

Tags: logic

Would you give me a hint how to solve these

1. Prove $2^{2n+1} + 3^{2n+1}$ is dividable by 5 for each $n \ge 1$ "
2. Prove that $x$ , $y$ any two rational then addition $x+y$ is rational .

I would be happy if you help

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the course name is set theory I swear

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what is the course I should write

Comment: The expression in your first part is ambiguous, you should at least use brackets to make clear what is meant. 2 ^ 2 n + 1 can be $2^2 n + 1$ or $2 ^{2 n } + 1$ or $2^{2 n +1}$...

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch im sorry

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA no understand use easy eng please

Comment: What have you tried in an attempt to solve the problem? Please show your work by editing your original post.

Comment: @Χpẘ  i couldn't solve it .. i can't even start .. i dont wan you tell me all answer just hint me

Comment: This won't solve the problem but it is often helpful: calculate the first few values of $n$. For example $n=1$ gives $2^3+3^3=8+27=35$, which is divisible by 5!.

Comment: @user430638: Just because the course name is "set theory" doesn't mean that these questions are set theory questions.

Comment: Another way to go is to just wait around a while and someone will just give you the answer, even though you just wanted a hint.

Comment: @Χpẘ why you say this ? If I want answer i will say me no lie just hit understand??

Comment: @AsafKaragila sorry I angry you i dont know what type this called in Eng , you can help dont anger

Comment: @user430638 I don't understand what you are saying. BTW, I was referring to the fact that someone posted a response that was the answer, not just a hint.

Comment: @Χpẘ it's his problem if I want to look final answer i can but i don't want i want just a hit pleve me or not

Comment: @user430638 I understand. The comment was really directed at him, not you. Probably didn't translate well. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Χpẘ ok no problem

Comment: BTW, looks like Srikant's answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints which leads to a longwinded solution for part(a):

1. Add and subtract $2^{2n} \cdot 3$.
2. Then consider $3^{2n+1} -  2^{2n} \cdot 3$. (Note: The other part of the expression is trivially divisible by 5.) Simplify to obtain $(3^2)^n-(2^2)^n$ and use polynomial long division to complete the proof.

Hint for part(b):

If $x$ and $y$ are rational then there must be integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $y=\frac{c}{d}$. Can you now show that $x+y$ is rational?

Comment: For a i get 1 you mean add and sub in same tame ? Why this value ? (2^(2n+1) . 3 ) ? Why ...... for b you mean that x+y = a/b+c/d ?

Comment: Yes, add and subtract at the same time so that the overall expression does not change like so: $2^{2n+1} + 3^{2n+1}=2^{2n+1} +2^{2n} \cdot 3+ 3^{2n+1}-2^{2n} \cdot 3$. For part (b): yes that is what I mean.

Comment: ok but why this value? I want to understand

Comment: Simplify the first two terms of the right-hand side and you will see why I chose that term. The task then reduces to showing that the second two terms are also divisible by $5$ which you can do using the hint no 2 for part (a).

Comment: thanks i get it .....I hope god gives you his mercy

Answer (score 0):

your term is equal to $$2\cdot 4^n+3\cdot 9^n\equiv 2\cdot (-1)^n+3\cdot (-1)^n=5\cdot(-1)^n\equiv 0 \mod 5$$

Comment: OP asked for a hint, not solution.